# How to fix a small ceiling corner?

Tags: ceiling

I have a ceiling corner above the stairs that needs to be repaired.  It was previously drywall on the vertical, and finished ceiling on the horizontal.  We caused some damage early on that I covered up and further prevented with a piece of angled aluminium - 2" x 2" at a 90 degree angle that I cut to length and screwed in to cover the angle.

Is there a common way to cover and protect this corner?  I'm not against redoing the drywall but if there's an easy way to cover and protect this corner I'd probably go with that.

Comment: A picture might help.

Comment: Yeah, pics tell far more than words - we could be looking at an inside corner, an outside corner, damage to a wall, to the ceiling, a hole exactly in the corner... something that can be easily patched with toothpaste or something that'll require replacing three 24"-square hunks of drywall.

Comment: There are actual corner guards for outside corners that you just silicone on, but yeah a picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are drywall/plaster corner protectors that are available for retail purchase and for commercial use. Basically they accomplish the same thing you did with your aluminum angle, except they are usually made of plastic. Other than that: plaster patch, sand smooth, plaster patch, sand smooth, ad nauseum...